# I want to do a push segue without animation, and it works fine on the simulator but not on device?

Tags: xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue, pushviewcontroller

I'm just working on storyboard right now, and the push segue doesn't animate on the simulator, but once i run it on device the left->right animation happens.  I've set it as a push segue with animation unchecked. I want it to not animate.

I've also tried it programmatically with

```
override func perform() {
    let source = sourceViewController as UIViewController
    if let navigation = source.navigationController {
       // navigation.showViewController(destinationViewController as UIViewController, sender: self)
        navigation.pushViewController(destinationViewController as UIViewController, animated: false)
    }
}
```

But I get an error with "unrecognized selector sent to instance." if I do it programmatically.  Again, it works perfectly on the simulator, but not on device

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: Are both the simulator and the device running the same iOS version?